# Application_OnError not always working

Tags: asp.net, exception, redirect, global-asax, application-onerror

I experience strange problem. We have error handling in global.asax  that would redirect user on special page in case if error happened:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    .......
    string pageError = "~/LastError.aspx?AfterNextClick=" + afterNextClick.ToString();
    if (Request["guid"] != null)
        pageError += "&guid=" + Request["guid"];
    Server.Transfer(pageError);
}
```

Custom errors are turned off.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Most of the times the Application_OnError works perfectly and redirects users to the specific page, but sometimes, users are not redirected anywhere and an ASP.NET exception page is displayed. 

So is there any situations in which Application_OnError in global.asax wouldn't fire?

Comment: Check whether the afterNextClick is null or empty before calling the ToString() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably an exception is ocurring inside the `Apllication_Error` method. Take a closer look at the code you place in this method (where you placed ...... ).

Try placing a `try/catch` block in this method to debug what's going on...

Comment: I think it is really it. I thought that if an exception happens in Appllication_Error then user would be displayed that exception, but instead the original excpetion is displayed. So thank you for the answer, it helped.

Comment: If it helped you, you should accept the answer and even vote it up... :)